# Should one always cast printf parameters?

Tags: c, c99

A while ago I was hunting for bug a that was causing wrong numeric data being written to log files. Turned out that the problem was that code equivalent to the following:

```
int main(void) {
    struct {
        double a;
        int b;
    } s = { 1, 2 };

    printf("%lf\n", s.a);
    printf("%lf\n", s.b);
}
```

was outputting

```
1.000000
1.000000
```

Apparently `printf` was expecting the second value in floating point registers, not in the stack. To prevent such mistakes from happening in the future, **should one cast all printf parameters to be sure that they really are of the expected type?**

Comment: *"Apparently printf was expecting the second value in floating point registers, not in the stack."* -- This is a very confused statement, nomenclature wise.  Look up the terms "register" and "stack" in a computer science dictionary and consider why they are meaningless and/or used very erroneously in this context.  I believe what you mean is something more along the lines of "Apparently printf was expecting the second value to be a floating point value, and not an integer value."

Comment: goldilocks, I don't see your confusion. For some architectures floating point arguments to functions are passed on the stack while integer arguments are passed in integer registers or the stack if no registers remain. If you mismatch the types of the value you pass and your printf format string, the behaviour the OP sees could well happen. The varargs handler might look on the stack but the compiler will have put the integer value in integer registers. (Though it is undefined behaviour, so all bets are off and reasoning about it is crazy!). Why do you feel the OP is confused?

Comment: @goldilocks more like "Apparently the implementation of printf was expecting the second value to be a floating point value, normally being passed in the floating point registers in the call convention of this architecture and operating system, and not an integer value, normally being passed either in general-purpose registers or in the stack."

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh : This is not ASM, and it is irrelevant whether or not the architecture even has floating point registers, much less how they are used or not used.  C is a specification, and discussing how an implementation may or may not work when trying to understand how C code is supposed to be written indicates *confusion*.

Comment: @goldilocks: Discussing how the implementation may or may not work can be important if you're trying to understand why a faulty program is behaving in a particular way, which can be helpful in tracking down and fixing the bug. Sure, the language standard says nothing about "the stack" or "registers", but compilers use such things to implement the language semantics. The OP's statement may well be perfectly correct (but incomplete).

Comment: The standard format for `double` is `%f` (which also works for `float`, because `float` arguments are promoted to `double`). `%lf` is equivalent to `%f`, but the extra `l` is not useful. (`%Lf` is for `long double`.) Is there some reason you *wanted* to use a floating-point argument for an integer argument?

Comment: @KeithThompson : I do feel bad for being a little snarky in my first comment, but *in this case* there is no way you will convince me that thinking of the implementation is anything but a distraction -- so I do not feel bad for trying to help the OP focus on what is and is not significant (although I am not surprised it was poorly received, since I was snarky...)  Note that the bridge you imply between "incomplete" and "correct" here is a lengthy one (`printf` does not consider *registers*, it considers *values*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should one cast all `printf` parameters to be sure that they really are
>   of the expected type?

Not generally. You should use the correct combination of format specifier and argument type for each argument you are passing. Of course, if you have an argument that is the "wrong type" (e.g. an `int` that you want to print using a floating point format specifier) then it needs to be converted in some way, which would typically mean a cast. But scattering a load of casts all over your `printf` lines "just in case" is not the right solution here.

Note that there is no requirement for the compiler to "understand" the format string of `printf` (or `scanf` or `strftime`, etc), so the compiler is just obliged to pass arguments according to a set list of restrictions (`float` is converted to `double`, short integers (`char`, `short`) are converted to `int`, and a few other things like that). Then it comes down to the `printf` to sort out what you have. And of course, if you don't have the right format specification for the argument, then `printf` may indeed look in the wrong place for the arguments.

So, in summary, you need to match the argument type for `printf`. If that means that you occasionally need a cast, then yes, use a cast. But it shouldn't be a "regular thing".

Comment: “float is converted to double, short integers (char, short) are converted to int, and a few other things like that” Actually, that is pretty much it (C99 6.5.2.2). I would call it *promotion*, though, rather than *conversion*.

Comment: Yes, that's perhaps a better word for it, but I don't know the exact wording of the C or C++ standard...

Comment: I just told you the wording of the C standard. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf 6.5.2.2:6 “These are called the _default argument promotions_” (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that I didn't look up the standard document before writing the answer - because I already know what happens with sufficient detail to give an answer. It is important in a standards document (or any other specification - I've been in meetings where one sentence is being discussed for quite some time to make sure it says "the exact right thing") to use words with specific meaning. In an answer on SO, as long as it conveys a correct message, not so important, so I'm not going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to C99 standard.
Mismatch in format specifier and datatype of actual data to be printed is `Undefined behavior`

Here `b` is and int so if you give `"%d"` in second `printf()` function.
It will print the correct value otherwise `Behavior is Undefined`

From c99

`7.19.6
9 If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned.242) If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is
undeﬁned`

Comment: +1 `s.b` is an int and is printed with `lf` which is causing the problem. Not sure where all the "register" vs "stack" and *casting* would fix etc come from.

Comment: I am fully aware of the root cause. The problem would have been avoided by explicitly casting the parameters to the same type as in the format string, `(double)` in this case. I was asking whether this is a recommended practice.

Comment: I got the question, in the way I answered.

Comment: @andyn, Of course it's not. Why not use the correct specifier in the first place?

Comment: @EricZ : Because s/he wants the output in floating point form.

Comment: Even if you want the output in floating point form you will have to use correct specifer as @EricZ said, otherwise it's undefined behavior, what's benefit to use it then.

Comment: The recommended practice is to use correct format specifiers. Think about other solutions(such as cast) only when this is not possible (E.g. in C89, certain format specifiers are not available).

Comment: @Omkant : I wasn't claiming it was a valid technique, just hypothesizing about the reason ;) But using a cast would make it valid.

Comment: No, you should put all warning flags on for your compiler, and he should detect the mismatch.

Comment: No, s/he should put warnings on and use a cast if s/he wants, or else use the correct specifier.

Comment: Yes, I'll go now and fix the hundred-and-something warnings in this project so that I can enable the -Werror flag.

Answer (score 2):

> should one cast all printf parameters to be sure that they really are of the expected type?

If the types are different than what would be expected, **yes**.  *If you enable warnings for your compiler, it will tell you this.*

I suspect you are acting on the belief that the template specifiers for printf indicate what style you would like a value displayed as.  This is partially true, and (via casting) can be made to work with the primary purpose, but **the primary purpose is to indicate to printf what  kind of value is being considered**.

So, if you have an integer type, you might use `%d`, but not `%f`, because `%f` would be a lie, and lying to a computer is a tricky business.  If the purpose of the `%f` is because you want the value printed with decimal places, then you should cast it; this will convert the integer value into a float properly.  (You could also just use `%d.000000` since an integer has no fraction anyway).

Otherwise, you should just use a specifier appropriate to the type.

Answer (score 1):

In your Your code `printf` takes the internal binary representation of the integer 2 and treats it as a float.

Instead of `cast all printf parameters to be sure that they really are of the expected type` you should make sure that whatever specifier you put in `printf` is the correct type. You know that `s.b` is an `int` so why use `%f`?

Comment: What if the struct definition changes later?

Comment: If the struct definition needs to change you are probably doing a change at design level so you might need to refactor. Consider for instance changing a member from an `int` to a `float*`, the `printf` being given a `%d` with a cast to `int`. The `printf` will now happily print the address of the pointer and you're none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if change the data type
from
    struct {
        double a;
        int b;
    } s = { 1, 2 };
to
    struct {
        double d_a;
        int n_b;
    } s = { 1, 2 };

Even you don't use Hungarian notation, just use some tag in your variables to deliver the type infor.
Then when you type printf("%lf\n", s.n_b);, it's easy to find the trap here.

C type cast has bad side effect in different platforms. They are tricky and sloppy.
If there is other way to solve issue, don't use type cast.